# Reading a Wav File

Tags: filters, audio, convolution, python

I need to read two .wav files. One of them is a song, and the other one is impulse response. Then, I have to convolve them.

In fact, I have read them by using `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` method. It returns two-dimensional array for each wav file. For the song, the array that it returns is of dimension 199001 x 2.

`This is the point that what I cannot understand. 
Why is column numbers equal to 2 ?`

The rows denote the samples, I guess. However, I do not know what columns refer to. To be honest, in signal processing lecture, we always encountered one value for each sample. However, in this case, there are two values for each sample.

Is there anyone who can explain this ?

Answer (score 3):

It means your song is stereo (two channels). if that's not the case, then that is weird indeed.

Comment: How can I convolve them ? Must each channel be convolved individually ?

Comment: yes.  each channel must be convolved individually.

Comment: Okey, I handled them. However, the problem is overflow during the computation of convolution. My signals consist of almost 197001 samples, and the sample values are very big. During the computation of convolution, I got overflow.

Comment: okay, now you gotta worry about the impulse response that you're convolving each channel with.  maybe those numbers are too big.